# macOS partition not showing up after High Sierra update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, partition, high-sierra, apfs

I updated my MacBook Pro mid 2015 to High Sierra from Sierra. Update was successful and everything worked perfectly for nearly 6 hours.
Then MBP hung and I had to hard power off since it wasn't responding for quite a while.

Now, that partition doesn't even exist. I had Boot Camp installed. Hence it automatically boots into Windows. No other drive shows up for boot options. Not even macOS recovery partition.

I made a bootable USB stick with macOS High Sierra from internet recovery, Disk Utility cannot fix it.

fsck_apfs says it is not a APFS container.
Windows lists it as HFS/HFS+.
diskutil lists - APFS container.

I need all the data on it since I had been working while the update happened which has no backup.
How do I recover that partition or at least all the data in it?

Note: Drive was not encrypted with FileVault.

Comment: oh hope you get better solution.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong. I have to start somewhere to fix it and I don't know where.

Comment: I have also decided to update. but I thought I will update after few releases.

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil list`, `diskutil ap list` and `sudo gpt -r show disk0`. A note like *"diskutil lists - APFS container."* isn't no useful detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try System Preferences -> Startup Disk -> macOS. I updated Sierra on my MBP (late 2016) and was unable to boot into Boot Camp. Fixed over the phone with Apple, but then I was unable to boot into macOS. They fixed that at the Apple store today using the above commands.

If you want to boot into Windows directly, just hold down the "option" key while you press power on button. This saves you from having to log in to macOS and then restarting while holding down the option key.

Comment: Problem was that it was booting to windows because macOS partition was not recognised, somehow macOS got corrupted everytime I hard power off.